# Having problem in Tic-Tac-Toe game pattern?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

when i run this code it return d['a'] for only j=1
what should i do to increment the value of j?

```
def pattern():
    d = {'a': '   |   |   ', 'b': '--- --- ---'}
    j = 1
    while j <= 11:
        if j not in [4,8]:
            return d['a']
        else:
            return d['b']
        j+=1
```

Comment: Once you `return` the method is over. On the first loop when `j` is `1` you `return d['a']` and the method is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are trying to get the pattern one by one every time look executes.
One alternative would be to put all the results in a array and then return the array.

```
def pattern():
    d = {'a': '   |   |   ', 'b': '--- --- ---'}
    j = 1
    result_pattern = []
    while j <= 11:
        if j not in [4,8]:
            result_pattern.append(d['a'])
        else:
            result_pattern.append(d['b'])
        j+=1
    
    # return your array and loop over it after function call.
    return result_pattern
```

You will use your function something like this:

```
p = pattern()
for item in p:
    # do something with your result.
```